# Is it acceptable that a user deletes his approved answer after I changed the accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, deleted-answers

Before changing the accepted answer on [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39338692/why-do-i-get-the-error-protocol-can-only-be-used-as-a-generic-constraint-beca/39351340?noredirect=1#comment66093902_39351340) I was hesitant but read [Is it poor form to switch accepted answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62252/is-it-poor-form-to-switch-accepted-answers) to be sure. Though I didn't read [Please show us when we lose an accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/please-show-us-when-we-lose-an-accepted-answer) until it was too late.

**Is there anyway to get that answer back? And is this the correct course of action?** I appreciated the answer, I upvoted it, accepted it.

I think everyone could benefit from it and specially the comments below it, but the answer itself didn't address as much as the newly accepted answer.

Also honestly I'm a bit frustrated. I thought I was doing something right for the community by changing the accepted answer while the other user **seemingly** thought differently.

Comment: It's unlikely the user disagreed with you. They likely agreed that the other answer was superior and didn't want to clutter up the answers section with extra information.

Comment: @MikeC The user left 3 other good links in his comments. They were really beneficial. I am not sure, maybe I'm just hypothesizing but I think it was done because they were displeased of my action.

Comment: If those links are in your browser history, you can suggest the user with the accepted answer add them to their answer.

Comment: @BSMP my question really is: Is it acceptable that a user just deletes their answer once their answer is no longer the accepted answer? I mean they were addressing it from different angles—at least in his comments...

Comment: I *think* you can delete an answer any time you want. I can't recall reading that an answer being accepted prevents you from deleting it. Someone would step in if you started deleting a bunch of your answers and others can vote to undelete something you've deleted but otherwise I don't think there are any restrictions.

Comment: I have personally, at least twice on Meta, deleted up voted answers.

Comment: @BSMP The accept stops you from being able to delete your answer yourself.  Note it does not stop 20Kers and mods from deleting it

Comment: @Honey I've deleted a number of my answers when I found that someone else had written it better than I could. I just consider it good curating, nothing personal or related to my answer getting "un-accepted." I'd do what BSMP suggested. If you still have access to those links, suggest that they are added to the accepted answer.

Comment: @MikeC So you're saying I'm thinking too much into it and the user was likely a pro and thought it's better for the community? OK

Comment: @Honey I think that's about right. Whether it actually was better for the community or not can be debated but I think they just made a judgement call. I wouldn't worry too much about it :)

Comment: It's very possible that the user thought the other answer was better *but* at the same time you have to imagine that it's a negative shock to that user to find out that their accepted answer and 15 rep points just got yanked away. So they may have been understandably upset by this and we should probably respect that and leave it be.

Comment: The deleted answer was provided by a user with almost 50k rep so I would think he knows what he is doing ([users with 10k rep can view deleted posts](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)). I know nothing about Swift so cannot comment if the answer was worthwhile keeping or not though. Unfortunately the comments he added have also been removed so I can't give you them here.

Comment: Deleted answer looks significantly lower quality compared to remaining one (I have no idea whether deleted answer is actually wrong in any way, just has no real explanation). I'd personally do the same and delete my answer if there is better one that covers the same topic (instead of bringing it up to the quality of other post).

Comment: @BSMP: Oh, I've deleted lots of upvoted answers on SO. The two typical scenarios are: I post an answer at about the same time someone else does and go do something else, then later I come back to it and see it's just covering the same ground as the other and either the other's been accepted or I just think theirs should stay rather than mine. Or I've misread the question, answered what I thought it was instead of what it was, had the answer upvoted, and then realized that it was answering the wrong question. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Or someone points out a pretty bad flaw in my reasoning in the answer and upon re-examining it I see there is little point in fixing it now that there's 3 other, better answers covering what I was gonna edit into anyways.

Comment: In my opinion, even if the reasoning for deleting was that the user felt that the op acted incorrect, I don't see how we could say what the user did was *unacceptable*. Immature, frustrated; maybe, but it is acceptable, since it was his/her answer

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/5228z for the < 10k users

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is acceptable. Maybe it's a bit disappointing to see upvoted (and presumably good) content removed without understanding why, but users can delete their own answers as they see fit. As mentioned in the comments, maybe they liked the newer answer better and didn't want to leave what they think is an inferior answer there. It could also be that they just realized they are unhappy with their own answer, regardless of the newly accepted one. That's their call to make.

What is not okay is maliciously deleting a lot of your own answers as one would do in a rage-quit. As long as there isn't a pattern of the user removing a good number of their own upvoted answers, I don't see a problem here.

Or maybe they really are petty and got jealous of the other answer being accepted. We don't know why it happened, and as long as there isn't a pattern of it, there's no reason to expend any more effort on figuring it out.

Comment: Based on the content of the question (see my post in the comments) vs the new accepted post, I probably would have deleted my answer, too. It doesn't really add anything, and it was really *really* short (especially compared to the newly accepted answer).

Answer (score 1):

#### Regarding the member that deleted an answer:

I find it perfectly okay to delete your own answer if a better answer pops up.

#### Regarding your change of "accepted answer":

If you find the later answer being more helpful for the problem at hand, I also find it okay to change "accepted answer". But maybe you should consider whether you approved the first answer too soon. If it didn't solve your problem, you shouldn't have accepted it. If it did solve your problem, I don't see any reason to change "accepted answer".

#### Regarding "good information in comments":

Comments should not be viewed as something valuable. Unfortunately some members prefer to post good information in comments even though comments have no value. The value for SO is the stuff posted inside question and answers.